# Actions on Google SDK can not use updatePermission

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working on an app for Google Home and Google assistant. I use firebase cloud functions for webhook.

I've been trying to get permission for push notification and used this link https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications as guide. However, whenever I try to reach update intent, I get an error.
When I try to debug it, I realized I can not reach inside of the if condition and even if I could make it, can't reach to 'setup_push' intent.
Here is the code I used:

```
    app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Do you want to get update?');
  conv.ask(new Suggestions('Alert me of new tips'));
  const userInput = conv.input.raw;
if ( userInput === 'Alert me of new tips') {
  app.intent('setup_push', (conv) => {
    conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({intent: 'sendNotif'})
    );
  });
}
});
```

Here is the error shown:

> expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data: The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found..

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have an intent called "sendNotif"? Was that setup in the Actions console as a notifiable intent?

Comment: yes I have "sendNotif" intent. Yet, it is not a notifiable intent. But even if I have it, I can not reach 'setup_push' intent. Do you think it is because of that?

Comment: I'd try adding it in to the console

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? Have you enabled push notification permission in User Engagement of your action? https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#console_setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started using DialogFlow SDK and changed it to this and worked. I suppose, problem was trying to use permission helper in same intent.

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({
    intent: 'sendNotif'
  }));
});


app.intent('finish_push_setup', (conv) => {
  if (conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {
    conv.close(`Ok, I'll start alerting you.`);
  } else {
    conv.close(`Ok, I won't alert you.`);
  }
});
```